# Adding ZIP values to existing dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Essentially I have a large file delimited by pipes (|). The file has a header followed by data. I want to put this file into a dictionary.

Example of the file:

```
A|B|C
1|2|3
4|5|6
```

I have so far done the following:

```
positions = open(pos_file, 'r')  # Opens the position file to read
positions.seek(0)

columns = [x.strip() for x in g1_positions.readline().split('|')]

pos_hash = {}
for data in positions:
    values = [x.strip() for x in data.split('|')]  
    pos_hash.update (zip(columns, values))  

print (pos_hash.items())
```

Issue with this though is that it fails to add multiple records and in this case only includes the last record.

What I wish to see is using the example above in a dictionary is:
`{ [(A:1), (B:2), (C:3)], [(A:4), (B:5), (C:6)] }`

However I feel the update function updates the overall dictionary instead of appending.

Comment: the required solution is invalid because `dict` requires `key:value` pair and `key' should be `hashable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below idea:

```
>>> columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> z = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
>>> 
>>> pos_hash = []
>>> 
>>> for item in z:
...   pos_hash.append(dict(zip(columns, item)))
... 
>>> pos_hash
[{'A': '1', 'C': '3', 'B': '2'}, {'A': '4', 'C': '6', 'B': '5'}]
```

Comment: Right looks like this might be the way I have to do this since my aim of doing this doesn't work. I will just have to keep a track of the index. Or just use my method but go one record at a time. Thanks!